# Proving that the lower Riemann sum of this modification of Dirichlet function is $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Consider the following variant of the Dirichlet function-- $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ where

$$f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{1}{b}\; \text{      if $x$ is rational and $x= \dfrac{a}{b}$ is in its lowest terms}\\
    5 \; \text{      $x$ is irrational}
    \end{cases}$$

I am trying to prove that the lower Riemann sum of $f$ is $0$. I am using a proof by contradiction. Essentially, I am trying to show that there exists no interval $[x_{j-1}, x_j] \subset [0, 1]$ over which $\inf\limits_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]} f >0$. This seems intuitive enough, I am having trouble coming up with a precise argument. Should I be using the limiting process somehow to complete the proof? What else can I try?

Comment: I feel like the proof by contradiction structure makes this particular problem more complicated. What one wants to prove directly is that for every interval $[c,d]\subset[0,1]$, one has $\inf_{x\in[c,d]} f(x) = 0$. Can one find a sequence of points $x_j\in[c,d]$ such that $f(x_j)\to0$?

Comment: @GregMartin I think a subsequence of the sequence $\{s_n\}$ should work where $\{s_n\} = \frac{1}{n}$ where $n \in\mathbb N$. We can take the subsequence depending on what $[c, d]$ is. How should I proceed from here? How does the limit connect to the infimum, conceptually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what follows, $a,b$ are always assumed to be integers.

As you have mentioned, you need to show that for any sub-interval $[c,d]$ of $[0,1]$,
$$
\inf_{[c,d]} f = 0.
$$
Since $f\ge 0$, it suffices to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you can find a point $a/b$ in $[c,d]$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{b} < \varepsilon.
$$
To this end, let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that
$$
\frac{1}{k} < \varepsilon.
$$
Notice that there are infinitely many rational numbers in the interval $[c,d]$. This fact readily follows from the density of the rationals.

However, there are only finitely many terms of the form $a/b$ for $b\in\mathbb{N}, b\le k$ in the interval $[c,d]$. Indeed, using that $[c,d]\subseteq [0,1]$ we see that the set
$$
\{a/b \in [c,d] : 1 \le b \le k\} \subseteq \bigcup_{b=1}^k\{a/b : 0 \le a \le b\}
$$
is finite.

Hence, there must be an elment $a/b$ in $[c,d]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ which is not in the aforementioned set. Then $b> k$ so that
$$
f(a/b) < \varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: for every open interval $(L, U)$ where $L < U$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a fraction in lowest terms $\frac{a}{b} \in (L, U)$ where $b > k$.

Proof: Since $L < U$, take a rational number $q_L \in (L, U)$. Since $q_L < U$, take another rational number $q_U \in (q_l, U)$. Then $[q_L, q_U] \subseteq (L, U)$. We will produce our fraction in the interval $[q_L, q_U]$.

Define $d = q_U - q_L$. Then consider the fact that for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, there are at most $j (d + 1)$ fractions in $[q_L, q_U]$ that can be written as $\frac{a}{j}$ for some $a$, since taking the smallest such $a$ with $\frac{a}{j} \in [q_L, q_U]$, we see that $\frac{a}{j} + \frac{(d + 1)j}{j} = \frac{a}{j} + (d + 1) \notin [q_L, q_U]$. Then there are at most $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^k j (d + 1)$ numbers in $[q_L, q_U]$. Pick some natural number $w > \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k j (d + 1)$.

Then consider the $w + 1$ numbers of the form $\frac{n q_L + (w - n) q_U}{w}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq n \leq w$. Each of these numbers is a rational number in the interval $[q_L, q_U]$. But there are more than $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^k j (d + 1)$ of these numbers, so there must be some which cannot be written as $\frac{a}{j}$ for some $j \leq k$. In other words, there must be one with a simplified form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $b > k$. The theorem is proved.

Now that we have this theorem in hand, we see that for every interval $(L, U)$ where $L < U$, we have simplified fractions with arbitrarily large values. This means that for all $\epsilon > 0$, we can take a natural number $k > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, find a fraction in lowest terms of the form $\frac{a}{b} \in (L, U)$ where $b > k > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, and compute $f(\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{1}{b} < \epsilon$. So no positive number is a lower bound for $\{f(x) | x \in (L, U)\}$. On the other hand, zero is clearly a lower bound. So $0 = \inf \{f(x) | x \in (L, U)\}$.

Comment: The theorem that you mentioned-- doesn't that follow directly from the density of rationals? What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that the rationals are dense guarantees that you have some $\frac{a}{b} \in (L, U)$, but it does not guarantee that the fully simplified denominator $b$ is greater than $k$.